# JavaScript - How do i change time of string

Tags: javascript, time, timezone, offset

I have a time like this:

```
12:30PM
```

And I want to change it by an hour offset (e.g: `-5`), plus if the time goes less than midnight it should display the previous date, which I can do; but the rest I cannot.

Does anyone have an idea how to do it, because I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
time="12:35PM";
```

get hours + minutes only

```
timearr=time.replace("PM","").replace("AM","").replace(" Yesterday","").replace(" Tomorrow","").split(":");
```

hours minus five

```
timearr[0]-=5;
```

Check if Yesterday

```
if(timearr[0]<0){ 
 timearr.push(" Yesterday");
 timearr[0]=timearr[0]%24;
}
```

Check if tomorrow:

```
if(timearr[0]>24){
timearr.push(" Tomorrow");
timearr=timearr%24;
}
```

Check if Ante Meridian or Post Meridian

```
if(timearr[0]>12){ 
 timearr[1]+="PM";
 timearr[0]-=12;
}else{
  timearr[1]+="AM";
}
```

Create Timestring again:

```
timearr[0]+=":";
time=timearr.join("");
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

```
moment().format();
```

returns the current date-time. eg: `"2017-01-28T14:52:59+02:00"`

```
moment().format('h:mm A');
```

returns current time. eg: `"2:54 PM"`

```
moment().add(5, 'hours').format('h:mm A');
```

returns current time plus 5 hours added to it. eg: `"7:54 PM"`

Comment: How would you are time to a string

Comment: I am not sure what exactly are you asking. Please refer to moment.js official documentation for further details on how it works.